# Jump Search Algorithm: Error in the pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm reading a book on Data Structures and Algorithms and currently I'm reading about a Jump Search algorithm. I think that there is an error in the pseudocode in the book (please check the code printed below). The jumps are not performed during the Step 3, and because of that the run-time is of the algorithm below is of order O(n) (and the run-time of the correctly implemented Jump Search algorithm is O(sqrt(n)).

All in all I think that there is an error in the Jump Search algorithm, however I might be wrong, and I would appreciate any help/comments. Thank you!

```
**JUMP_SEARCH (A, lower_bound, upper_bound, VAL, N)**

Step 1: [INITIALIZE] SET STEP = sqrt(N), I = 0, LOW = lower_bound, HIGH = upper_bound, POS = –1
Step 2: Repeat Step 3 while I < STEP
Step 3:
    IF VAL < A[STEP]
        SET HIGH = STEP – 1
    ELSE
        SET LOW = STEP + 1
    [END OF IF]
    SET I = I + 1
[END OF LOOP]

Step 4: SET I = LOW
Step 5: Repeat Step 6 while I <= HIGH
Step 6:
    IF A[I] = Val
        POS = I
        PRINT POS
        Go to Step 8
    [END OF IF]
    SET I = I + 1
[END OF LOOP]
Step 7: IF POS = –1
    PRINT "VALUE IS NOT PRESENT IN THE ARRAY"
[END OF IF]
Step 8: EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right. The pseudo code has quite a few issues:

1. Step 3 always makes the same comparison as `STEP` is not modified in the loop. So this means that in this loop either `HIGH` is set, or `LOW` is set, but never the two. If `LOW` is set, then the search will still take *O(n)* as you rightly indicate. The index for `A` should change in that loop, and make the "jumps".
2. When `HIGH` is set in that loop, the loop should exit immediately.
3. When `LOW` is set, the `+ 1` is also wrong, as it does not consider that the preceding element might be the value being looked for.
4. Even though there is a parameter for a specific `lower_bound`, this variable is only used for the initialisation of `LOW` at the start, but then in the actually access to `A` it is never used.
5. It is strange that `N` is a parameter, since logically `N = upper_bound - lower_bound + 1`. So this can only lead to further inconsistency.

Concluding: there are too many errors in this pseudo code for it to be helpful.

Comment: The tricky thing about the code is that it gives the right answer, but its performance is O(n) instead of O(sqrt(n)). ( The performance of the correctly implemented Jump Search algorithm is supposed to be O(sqrt(n)). )

Comment: It does not *always* give the right answer. If the value being searched is unique, and sits at A[STEP], then it will not be detected because of point (3). Secondly, if lower_bound > STEP, and the searched value is below the lower_bound, it might be found there, while it shouldn't. Similar problem with the higher_bound.

Comment: Of course, the correct *O(sqrt(n))* algorithm (in pseudo code) is available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_search)